# NetSuite - Populate 'Item Defined Cost' based on 'Preferred Vendor Cost'

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a workflow in NetSuite that will update the 'Item Defined Cost' based on the cost from the 'Preferred Vendor' or the 'Average Cost', whichever is higher. However, I am having trouble referring to the cost specifically from the vendor marked as 'Preferred Vendor'. Is this possible?

Comment: On which record type is this "item defined cost"?

Comment: This field is found on inventory item records and the id is {costestimate}

Comment: Also, when do you want this workflow to run, will it be event based(on create, edit etc of inventory item) or will it run on a schedule? If you could elaborate on when the 'Item defined cost' needs to be updated, that would help anyone to suggest a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the exact context on when you want to update the field value. But if you are creating a workflow just for updating a field value i would suggest you to use a script where you could have lot of options to proceed with and also could have better performance.

Also, checking preferred vendor is working with a sublist. So I would suggest to go for a script. If it is something that the field should update during a particular state of a workflow then you could use workflow action script as well.